# Xcode "Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Float'"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a BMI calculator that takes the user's height and weight as inputs then calculates their BMI; from there, it uses a series of if-else statements to return a message to the user that states if they are healthy/over/underweight. I have no problem getting the program to return the calculated BMI value; but when I incorporate the if-else statement, I get the "Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Float'" error.

Here's my code (I've only done one if-else statement so far):

```
import UIKit

func bodyMassIndex (userHeight : Float, userWeight : Float) -> String {

    let userHeightSquared = (userHeight*userHeight)

    let userWeight = userWeight

    let userBMI = (userWeight/userHeightSquared)

    return userBMI

    if userBMI > 25 {
      return "Overweight"
    } 
}

print(bodyMassIndex (userHeight : 1.82, userWeight: 90.7))
```

Comment: `bodyMassIndex` suppose to return `String`, but you are returning `Float`. `return userBMI`. Make this to return string like `return String(userBMI)`.

Comment: What sense does it make to return from the function *before* the value of `userBMI` is checked?

Comment: Also the actual error message for that code would be "cannot convert return expression of type 'Float' to return type 'String'" – which is *not* what you wrote in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wrap the `Float` value of `userBMI` into a `String`.

```
func bodyMassIndex (userHeight : Float, userWeight : Float) -> String {

    let userHeightSquared = (userHeight*userHeight)

    let userWeight = userWeight

    let userBMI = (userWeight/userHeightSquared)

    return String(userBMI)

    if userBMI > 25 {

        return "Overweight"

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic looks a little confused here:

```
return userBMI
if userBMI > 25 {
    return "Overweight"
}
```

What is your function supposed to do? Return a BMI number, or a descriptive String? (It's trying to do both, and the compiler isn't happy)

If I were a user, I'd want to see both the number *and* a statement about what it means - so you'd need two functions:

```
func bodyMassIndex (userHeight : Float, userWeight : Float) -> String {
  let userHeightSquared = (userHeight*userHeight)
  let userWeight = userWeight
  let userBMI = (userWeight/userHeightSquared)
  return userBMI
}

func bodyMassDiagnosis (bodyMassIndex : Float) {
  if userBMI > 25 {
    return "Overweight"
  }
  return "You're doing fine"
}
```

And then:

```
let bodyMassIndex = bodyMassIndex(height, weight)
let diagnosis = bodyMassDiagnosis(bodyMassIndex)
self.indexLabel.text = "BMI \(bodyMassIndex)"
self.diagnosisLabel.text = diagnosis
```